# Including a column twice in a PostgreSQL index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building a PostgreSQL based work-queue as described [here](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/).

My queue definition differs slightly from the concept described in the article by using a target timestamp for consumption (`due_time`):

```
CREATE TABLE publish_queue
(
  id INT generated BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  article_id INT NOT NULL,
  due_time TIMESTAMP NULL,
  is_complete BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  completed TIMESTAMP NULL,
  created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

There's a single index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_publish_due_created ON publish_queue(
due_time ASC NULLS FIRST, created ASC) WHERE(NOT is_complete);
```

Let's fill the table with a test dataset:

```
begin transaction;
INSERT INTO publish_queue(article_id, due_time)
SELECT 2407, t.day::date FROM generate_series(timestamp '2024-03-07', timestamp '2034-08-16',interval  '1 minute') AS t(day);
commit;
```

And consume an item:

```
update publish_queue
set is_complete = true, completed = now()
where id = (
  select id
  from publish_queue
  WHERE NOT is_complete AND (LOCALTIMESTAMP >= due_time OR due_time IS NULL)
  order by due_time ASC NULLS FIRST, created ASC
  for update skip locked
  limit 1
)
returning article_id;
```

On my system the query takes ~2 seconds to complete with the following execution plan:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/oLYI

BUT, if I change the index like below, including the `due_time` a second time - something I have never done before ...

```
CREATE INDEX idx_publish_due_created ON publish_queue(
due_time, due_time ASC NULLS FIRST, created ASC) WHERE(NOT is_complete);
```

the query takes 60ms and results in this plan:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/U3LA

Now my question is, it feels weird to include a column two times in a index. Am I missing something here? Could the same be achieved using a different index or rephrasing the query?

Comment: What if you only include it once without `nulls first`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was it. Could you turn the comment into an answer in order for me to accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is weird. You can do better:

```
CREATE INDEX ON (coalesce(due_time, '-infinity'::timestamp), created);
```

Then query like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM publish_queue
WHERE NOT is_complete
  AND LOCALTIMESTAMP >= coalesce(due_time, '-infinity'::timestamp)
ORDER BY coalesce(due_time, '-infinity'::timestamp), created
FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name's remark was spot on but this is works as well.